# Fragment killed onActivityResult

Tags: android, androidx, dagger, android-architecture-navigation

I have an Activity using all latest tech trend

```
class MyActivity {


 override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {

        val current = (nav_host_fragment as NavHostFragment).childFragmentManager.fragments[0]

        if (current is ActivityResultReceiver) {
            current.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        }
    }

}


class MyFragment  : DaggerFragment, ActivityResultReceiver {

    @Inject
    lateinit var viewModelFactory: ViewModelProvider.Factory

    private val viewModel by activityViewModels<SwipeViewModel> {
        viewModelFactory
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        viewModel.onActivityResult(ActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data))
    }
}
```

I have some crashes when the viewModelFactory is null in fragment.

```
Caused by java.lang.RuntimeException
Failure delivering result ResultInfo{who=null, request=65636, result=0, data=null} to activity}: kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException: lateinit property viewModelFactory has not been initialized
android.app.ActivityThread.deliverResults (ActivityThread.java:4423)
com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main (ZygoteInit.java:873)
Caused by kotlin.UninitializedPropertyAccessException
lateinit property viewModelFactory has not been initialized
SwipeFragment.getViewModelFactory (SwipeFragment.java:7)
SwipeFragment$viewModel$2.invoke (SwipeFragment.java:2)
SwipeFragment$viewModel$2.invoke (SwipeFragment.java)
```

I understand MyActivity can be killed when it's behind a startActivityForResult Activity. what about the lifecycle of the fragment? why is recreated but its injection becomes null? what is the solution in this case?

Comment: Did you ever figure out a solution to this?